# Is this a transitive relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

$$A = \{foo, bar\}$$

$$R_1 = \{(foo, foo)\}$$

$$R_2 = \{(foo, bar)\}$$

Is $R_1$ transitive on $A$? My gut tells me yes, but I'm not sure if transitivity requires $3$ elements.

What about $R_2$? foo R2 bar ^ foo R2 bar => foo R2 bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s transitive. If it weren’t, you’d be able to find $a,b,c\in A$, not necessarily distinct, such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in A$, $\langle b,c\rangle\in A$, and $\langle a,c\rangle\notin A$, and you can’t: the only way to get $\langle a,b\rangle\in A$ and $\langle b,c\rangle\in A$ is to set $a=b=c=\text{foo}$, in which case $\langle a,c\rangle$ **is** in $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Transitivity requires three elements, but they need not be distinct. This is one of the many reasons why mathematicians are considered strange by laypeople. We say *three*, but we really mean *three, two or one*.

Answer (score 1):

The relation $R$ is transitive if whenever $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$ then $(a,c)\in R$.

Since $R$ is a singleton there is only one pair so $\newcommand{\foo}{\mathbf{foo}}(\foo,\foo)\in R$ as well $(\foo,\foo)\in R$ and indeed $(\foo,\foo)\in R$.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**  it is transitive.

Proof :

defination of Transitivity :**if ( aRb and bRC )then { aRc}**

here (foo, foo) is aRb..where a=foo and b=foo .

Since there is nothing to represent bRc, the condition ( aRb and bRC ) is false

defination of if...then

[image: if..then]

By the defination of if...then , we can say when p is false the answer is true as can be seen from the image.

THUS , The Given Relation is Transitive :)